# Device resolution and fixed width in pixels

Tags: html, css, screen, screen-resolution

Imagine devices with resolutions 
a) 300px x 400px
b) 600px X 800px
c) 900px x 1000px

Now if create a web page with a div whose width is 150px. Irrespective of all other factors (including browser)

it should occupy half of width in first device.
1/3rd of width in the second device.
1/4th of width in the third device.

However, the absolute size of the div depends on the screen size.

This was my assumption. This held good in few devices and breaks in others. What other dimension am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

#### It depends on screen resolution.

Consider an old iphone and an iphone with retina dispay.
The old iphone's screen is 320 x 480 pixels.
The iphone with retina display has a 640 x 960 pixels screen.

However, both screens are the same physical size (3.5 inches) and a 300 pixels wide square is rendered at the same physical size on both.

Both devices have a *logical* screen size of 320 x 480 points :

- On an old iphone, every point is 1 x 1 pixel.
- On an iphone with retina display, every point is 2 x 2 pixels.

When you set `width: 150px`, it'a actually 150 points.
A zoom-factor of 2 is applied on the iphone with retina display.
The square is actually rendered 300 pixels wide to match the physical size of the non-retina one.

#### See this site for size table : [screensiz.es](http://screensiz.es/phone)

- Width gives you the actual pixel width.
- Device with gives you the logical width.
- Pixel density gives you the zoom factor.

#### Check the Galaxy SIII for exemple :

Pixel density is 200% (zoom-factor of 2), width is 720 but device-width is actually 360 (device-width divided by zoom-factor => 720 / 2).